# NODE_PATH is consumed by atom, it replaces my already in place NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js, npm, atom-editor, pty, platformio

I'm on a windows 10 environment writing a plugin for the Atom text editor to allow running tests through protractor cucumber from within atom it consumes the PlatformIO-Terminal plugin's provided service. When I activate that terminal plugin from within Atom I'd expect to be able to execute any old program from it that I could from my terminal that it's emulating through pty.

I'm having trouble executing any node program I've installed via npm outside of Atom's apm. Further digging via printing the environment variable NODE_PATH from within that terminal revealed that Atom has eaten my NODE_PATH value, not appended it's own but completely consumed and replaced it. Resetting it from within that pty window doesn't work, and neither does adding it to the "Shell Environment Variables" from within the PlatformIO configuration terminal. I've installed 3 plugins which allow pulling in environment variables from the OS, and none of them have succeeded.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I can access the executable modules directly, but they call other ones and depend on NODE_PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't having success with terminal packages, you might try [`process-palette`](http://atom.io/packages/process-palette). It allows you to precisely define all of the details of the command, including environment variables. I've made an Atom command that sets `NODE_ENV` to an arbitrary string before executing a terminal command. Screenshots below:

[image: Process Palette command definition.]

[image: Process Palette environment variables.]

Below is a `process-palette.json` file that defines the command I wrote. All you have to do to get started is install the package, make that file with the following code, and select `Packages -> Process Palette -> Edit Configuration`.

```
{
  "patterns": {
    "P1": {
      "expression": "(path):(line)"
    },
    "P2": {
      "expression": "(path)\\s+(line)",
      "path": "(?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+"
    }
  },
  "commands": [
    {
      "namespace": "process-palette",
      "action": "env",
      "command": "echo %NODE_PATH%",
      "arguments": [],
      "cwd": null,
      "inputDialogs": [],
      "env": {
        "NODE_PATH": "wargarble"
      },
      "keystroke": null,
      "stream": true,
      "outputTarget": "panel",
      "outputBufferSize": 80000,
      "maxCompleted": 3,
      "autoShowOutput": true,
      "autoHideOutput": false,
      "scrollLockEnabled": false,
      "singular": false,
      "promptToSave": true,
      "saveOption": "none",
      "patterns": [
        "default"
      ],
      "successOutput": "{stdout}",
      "errorOutput": "{stdout}\n{stderr}",
      "fatalOutput": "Failed to execute : {fullCommand}\n{stdout}\n{stderr}",
      "startMessage": null,
      "successMessage": "Executed : {fullCommand}",
      "errorMessage": "Executed : {fullCommand}\nReturned with code {exitStatus}\n{stderr}",
      "fatalMessage": "Failed to execute : {fullCommand}\n{stdout}\n{stderr}",
      "menus": [
        "env"
      ],
      "startScript": null,
      "successScript": null,
      "errorScript": null,
      "scriptOnStart": false,
      "scriptOnSuccess": false,
      "scriptOnError": false,
      "notifyOnStart": false,
      "notifyOnSuccess": true,
      "notifyOnError": true,
      "input": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this one right now, thanks for the response.

Comment: If you look at my answers here and on the Atom forum, you'll see that I'm a big fan of the package. It's really a Swiss Army Knife for anything you do in a terminal with the exception that the output isn't an interactive shell. And the things where I do need an interactive shell are mostly things I prefer to do in [`cmder`](http://cmder.net), so it works out well.

Comment: Is there already a way to dynamically insert the string into the package for direct run? Part of the plugin I've written, is a string builder that inserts the resulting string and should execute it.

Comment: What string are you referring to?

Comment: So that'll be the shell command itself and potentially the working directory. A lot of plugins allow you to consume the package as a service in another package allowing you to call the commands directly from coffeescript or javascript. I'm wondering if you know if I can do something like that with process-palette. I'm marking your answer a winner either way, this solution totally worked for me, thanks.

Comment: If you scroll all the way down, you'll see a list of input variables. You can copy text to the clipboard and then use the `{clipboard}` variable if that accomplishes your objective. I have a command that doesn't do anything except take the line where the cursor is and run that, which I use for `npm install` and similar one-off instructions.

Comment: Not perfect but that's an awesome work around thanks. I've messaged the package writer about extending their package using the Atom Service API. That's all I'll be needing now for this, thanks for the help.